# What statistical model is this study using?

Tags: medicine

I am new to statistics and I need to know how to describe the statistical model of this study in my abstract. A retrospective medical study assessing the risk factors predisposing someone to a an infection by a certain microorganism. Patients who were proven to have been infected by this pathogen were compared based on their age, gender, co-morbidities. The results were entered into an excel spreadsheet.

The following results are just examples:
- 60% of those infected were men and 40% women 
- 55% of those infected were 60 and above years of age
- 70% of those infected had cardiovascular disease

Using this data we can conclude that gender, age and co-morbidities do play a role in this infection. Men are at a higher risk, the older the patient the higher risk and CVD patients have the highest risk.

Is the statistical method being used here regression analysis?
If not what is it?

Comment: Link to the paper?

Comment: The reason papers have methods sections and tables of statistical output is because that shows what statistical procedures they are using.  This kind of qualitative description can at best hint at what the researchers might have been doing.

Comment: Duplicated at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439475/what-statistical-method-am-i-using-in-this-study